# How to debug application which is using /dev/port using gdb

Tags: linux, c++, gdb

I've got a simple C++ code to work with old ISA card

```cpp
fd = open("/dev/port", O_RDWR);
if (fd == -1)
{
    Error() << "Error fd = -1" << msg_show;
    return;
}
```

and also I've done:

```
sudo setcap cap_sys_rawio=ep myapp
```

If I start the application using `./myapp`, then everything is fine, but if I start debug session using:

```
 gdb myapp
```

then I get:  `error "fd = -1"`

I've also tried to set `cap_sys_rawio` to `gdb`

```
sudo setcap cap_sys_rawio=ep /usr/bin/gdb
```

with no positive results. How can I debug my application?

Comment: It looks like the way i have tried is not coreect. Have made a simple driver for that old isa card. This driver made a file in /dev which permissions can be set ysing simple chmod. Works like a charm

Comment: Congratulations on figuring out the problem yourself. You may want to post this as an answer to your own question, so that others facing a similar issue may find it more easily. You could perhaps summarize the steps that were necessary for creation of the driver, or link to an online resource that explains that aspect ...

Answer (score 0):

Okay. The most right way in my situation was a write a simple driver which is used a couple of a ports and provide /dev/myport device which permissions could be changed using chmod.

I've made a repo with my example driver

https://github.com/qmor/AIC12202